# How to add a value between a dom element?

Tags: javascript

This is my element:

```
<var mathquill-command-id="56"></var>
```

I want to add something between like this:

```
<var mathquill-command-id="56">HERE</var>
```

This is my process so far:

```
const p = document.createElement('var')
p.setAttribute('mathquill-command-id', '56')
this.p.value = 'HERE'
this.main.append(p)
```

this.main is the parent element.

But it looks like .value does not work. I got the idea to use .value from how textbox element works.

Comment: `p.innerText = 'HERE';`

Comment: `p.textContent = "HERE";`

Comment: If you need to use the variable, `p.innerText = this.main.value;`

Comment: If `this.main` is a container element, it doesn't have a value. That's only for user inputs.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
p.innerHTML = 'HERE'
```

Comment: `innerText` or `textContent` would be better/safer

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer. "Do this: code" and "Try: code" don't help people learn. Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

> element.value can only be used on input Element,so you shoud use p.innerHtml or p.innerText

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).